# How does Github do localization?

Tags: rest, localization, github

They seem to go against the advice

> You may be tempted to store the chosen
>   locale in a session or a cookie. Do
>   not do so. The locale should be
>   transparent and a part of the URL.

from the official [Rails I18n guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-and-passing-the-locale)

I tried seeing if they set a cookie for the locale, and it seems like they don't.

So how do they do it and why they chose not to use URLs for different languages, like http://github.com/en/foo, http://github.com/fr/foo, etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

It uses the _gh_sess cookie to store that information.

Multiple URLS are sometimes avoided because they create something looking a lot like duplicate content for search engines. This can deplete your Google Karma and lead to poor SEO performance.

Comment: Hey! Lovely explanation.. How do you know they use _gh_sess? To me the value of _gh_sess looks random.

Comment: I changed my locale, deleted the cookie, refreshed, and It came back to english. And tried again from scratch. As you mention, there is no URL involved in the translation, so this is pretty obvious that the cookie is THE guilty one :)